# Rebase a GitHub pull request on top of my newer local commits

Tags: git, github, rebase, pull-request

Suppose I am locally on the branch `master` of our blessed repository. Someone has sent in a pull request.

How do I apply the commits of that pull request on top of my local branch - as if those commits were rebased on my branch - in a single command?

Note: the pull request is several days old, and my local branch has new commits since the pull request has been created.

Comment: I also asked a [similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182624/contributing-to-project-on-github-how-to-rebase-my-pull-request-on-top-of-mast) which may help out someone with the same problem

Answer (score 7):

There's a [great blog post](http://www.somethingorothersoft.com/2012/05/22/pulling-github-pull-requests-with-git/) on the subject, from [Igor Zevaka](http://www.somethingorothersoft.com/)

You first have to fetch the hidden pull request ref, and place it under the `pr/NNN` remote branch:

```
git fetch origin refs/pull/1234/head:refs/remotes/pr/1234
```

(replace `1234` by the pull request number)

After this it's just a classical rebase: checkout the pull request, and rebase it on your `master` branch:

```
git checkout pr/1234
git rebase master
```

or alternatively

```
git rebase master pr/1234
```

You might of course see conflicts.

Now the pull request is rebased on `master`, and is the current branch. If you want to update master just merge the pull request (we say `--ff-only` because we know it'll be a fast-forward merge):

```
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only pr/1234
```

To have a one-liner some shell aliasing is required, it's just a matter of scripting :)

Comment: 1. when `pr_1234` is checked out, doing `git rebase master` will rebase `pr_1234` on `master` (see http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

Comment: 2. because I'm not sure if a remote branch with slashes can be checked out as-is, and the original blog post does it this way

Comment: I've been away from git for too much time! of course after rebase `master` is still an ancestor of the pull request... I prefer the merge command, more intuitive even if the result is the same (also I upvoted one of your answers)

Comment: That's how I do it now - manually. *It strikes me as a very common scenario. It's odd that there's no git command to do this out-of-the-box.*

Answer (score 1):

OK, this one-liner will rebase your commits on top of the pull request (which is the inverse of what you want; see my other answer):

```
git pull --rebase origin pull/NNN/head
```

Where `NNN` is the pull request number. This assumes `origin` is your Github remote on your local repo, and `master` is checked out.

[Explanation here](https://community.jboss.org/blogs/stuartdouglas/2011/09/06/merging-github-pull-requests?_sscc=t) on Douglas Stuarts' blog: Github stores pull requests from other forks in your `origin` repo, under `pull/NNN`. This is what allows to run `pull --rebase` on it.

Comment: hah (/me deletes answer) - I wasn't at a machine yesterday to verify that works. That'll put the "local branch has new commits" on top of the pr commits - it's not clear from the question if that's fine or not. +1.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it's what the OP was looking for, but it is a clever answer.

Comment: Indeed the inverse of what I want, but interesting side note none the less :)

Answer (score 0):

Install [hub](http://hub.github.com/)

```
# directly apply all commits from a pull request to the current branch
$ git am -3 https://github.com/github/hub/pull/134
```

TODO: need to figure out how to force a --rebase